# Reading / Writing a File in C++

Tags: c++, file, io

while attempting to read/write my program writes to the file correctly but does not read properly.

Where l, w, n are `ints` and `transposed` is a `bool`.

```
void Matrix::operator >> (ifstream & f)
{
    f >> l; //length (int)
    f >> w; //width (int)
    f >> n; //size (int)
    f >> transposed; //(bool)

    theMatrix = vector<double>(0);
    double v;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        f >> v;
        cout << " pushing  back " << v << endl;
        theMatrix.push_back(v);
    }
}

void Matrix::operator<<(ostream & o)
{
    o << l;
    o << w;
    o << n;
    o << transposed;

    //theMatrix is a vector<double>
    for (double v : theMatrix) {
        o << v;
    }
}
```

I am assuming the issue is due to the read `operator >>` does not know how many bytes to read from while the write `operator <<` is not writing a set amount of bits/bytes. Is there a way to clarify how many bytes to read/write from so my program writes accordingly?

I am not new to C++ but I am new to its IO structure. I am spoiled on Java's serialization methods.

Comment: Just before `operator<<` generates the output, it creates a completely empty `vector`, and attempts to print the contents of this empty vector. Unsurprisingly, no output results. Where exactly did you expect the output to come from, in that empty vector?

Comment: The usual way is to overload the freestanding operator functions `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream, const Matrix&)` and `std::istream& operator>>(std::istream, Matrix&)`.

Comment: `<<` and `>>` are not used for binary I/O, they read and write formatted data. You need to put spaces between each value when you write it, so that the input function will know where each number ends.

Comment: Off topic: S l v a u . In case you had trouble interpreting that vital concept, expanded out to readability it says, "Single letter variables are useless."

Comment: @Sam V --> Thanks, silly mistake on my part.

Comment: @Barmar could you elaborate on how to do that?

Comment: @Jjoseph Investigate about `read()` and `write()` functions regarding binary files. Otherwise always put a separating space with your output.

Comment: @Jjoseph `o << l << ' ' << w << ' ' << n << ' ' << transposed << ' ';`

Comment: @Barmar much thanks, your suggestion made it work. Is there anyway I can give you credit for giving the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need whitespace between the values you're printing, so that when you read it back in it knows where each value end. Put a space between each of them. And the proper way to define the output operator for a type `T` is with the signature `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream, const T&)`

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream o, const Matrix& m)
{
    o << m.l << ' ' << m.w << ' ' << m.n << ' ' << m.transposed << ' '; 

    //theMatrix is a vector<double>
    for (double v : m.theMatrix) {
        o << v << ' ';
    }
}
```